# Debug on the Samsung Galaxy I7500 Android Phone

Tags: java, android

I am having Samsung Galaxy phone and i am trying it to connect to my Vista ,I have installed the Samsung PC suite . When i start the USB debugging on it asks for new driver , i give the path for sdk but still it never worked .
The firmware version of phone is 1.5 .I am having sdk 1.6.
I have done some changes in inf file but still no luck
What wrong i am doing ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: with ref to above the device is installed properly but now in eclipse is not recognizing the device .what wrong i am doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thread might be of some help: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3293